# Atomic multiple operations in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, atomic

Consider a schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
...
followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
...
}
```

When `userA` follows `userB`, `userB` is to be pushed in `userA.following` and `userA` is to be pushed in `userB.followers`. Both operations require a `.save()`.

What is a good way - perhaps conceptual - of ensuring that if either one of the `.save()` fails, both documents are left untouched?

Comment: Could you do without maintaining the `followers` list? Is it absolutely necessary? You could get the `followers` by querying the `following` fields of other users. If you could remove that it would be a single Atomic operation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just made an example of where atomicity may be required. To make a more general example, consider the Story-Author refs example on the [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). What to do if I created the Story, but something went wrong when adding the ref to the the author's document?

Comment: See if this helps - http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/

Comment: @BatScream interesting reading. I think it gives the conceptual framework I was looking for. Thanks. How to implement this in Node.js-Mongoose is not intuitive, but I have something to reflect on. Just as a comment, I am a bit surprised by the fact that there is very little talking about Atomicity-Isolation-Consistency in the Nodejs community. Is it my perception or I am missing something?

Comment: If we were to follow @BatScream's suggestion by querying the `following` fields, I was worried that it would add too much lookup time with a certain `userB` buried in arrays of different users, and I am okay with sacrificing some space for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I turned out doing as @BatScream suggested in the first comment. I reorganized the Schemas of my data and removed the list `followers`.

After reading quite a lot on the topic my humble conclusion is that doing transactions across multiple documents in mongoDB/Mongoose.js is, though doable, probably not the smartest-safest thing to do. When implementing two-phase commits rollback actions can themselves fail.

If atomic operations across multiple documents are necessary probably MongoDB is not the right tool. However, a bit of data restructuring/reorganization can perhaps some times make multidocument transactions unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use Mongoose's transaction API https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html . This lets you execute multiple queries in isolation and undo all of them if anyone of them fails